# Compiling and running linux test project

Tags: linux, compiling, testing

I'm trying to install *[Linux Test Project (LTP)](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/)* on Debian 6.0.2, kernel 2.6.33.20. Compilation and installation went fine and without errors, but when I try to run basic tests

```
$ ./runltp
```

I get following error:

```
FATAL: LTP not installed correctly
INFO:  Follow directions in INSTALL!
```

After inspecting `runltp` script I realised that I'm missing all `bin` directories in LTP (./bin, ./testcases/bin, ...). I followed all instructions in INSTALL and installed all dependencies. How can I fix that?

Comment: So after following all of the instructions in INSTALL, you still get the `LTP not installed correctly` error?

Comment: @BryanGarza Exactly!

Comment: Just to be clear, you are aware that LTP is packaged for Debian, right?

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced this issue. This issue got solved by placing ltp folder inside /opt directory and recompiling all files using make.